# MediaPlayer streaming : where is save tempory file?

Tags: android, media-player

I use the MediaPlayer to read an MP3 file saved on the network.
For security question, I would like to know if the file (or a part of them) is saved on the device (where) and if the file can be readed later after an extract on a PC for example.

Let me know if you have any information about it.

Edit : I use HTTP protocol and the file can be mp3 or ogg.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: which protocol is used to retrive the mp3  ? http/rtsp/https

Comment: I added the protocol and file format. Thanks

Comment: To my understanding, there is no way of accessing the buffered/completed file once it's completed. All the buffering etc is done native. I needed to access videos once they were finished buffering so I could play them back without buffering them again later. I resorted to coping the entire VideoView.java and building my on buffering mechanism and playing back the video using RandomAccessFiles and a FileDescriptor instead. So in terms of security i guess you are safe, unless the user has a rooted phone, but I doubt that he can access the partial/completed files anyway.

Comment: Thanks Freedman it's a good start for me...If anybody has an idea, let me know.

Comment: Did you manage to do this? @arnouf